# Get type of place where user is

Tags: kotlin, flutter

I would like to get name of object when user is. For example: Church, Cinema.

Can I use a GoogleMap, get user location and instead return Longitude and Latitude get object? Flutter or Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for google places API;

```
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
```

you can find an example of a JSON after using the api on this section:

```
 https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#find-place-responses
```

and in that JSON, there is this data(among many others):

```
 "name" : "Museum of Contemporary Art Australia",
 "types" : [ "travel_agency", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
```

I think you could start studying it from that point, there is a lot more of information returned in the JSON you can see in that link